# Is there a way to protect eyes from negative effects of computer and mobile screen?

Tags: eye, computers, eye-strain, lenses

People who work on computer and smartphone during most hours of the day are prone to impacts of the light of these screens. I have read about the negative effects of the light from screen. So I was wondering if we have to technology that can protect the eyes from the damage these screen pose to the eyes.

Are there any specific types of glasses or anything else that can help?

https://www.webmd.com/eye-health/qa/can-staring-at-a-computer-screen-for-too-long-damage-my-eyes